# Copy shortcut key can not be used with error

Tags: xcode, macos

Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/167y6.png)

Copy shortcut key can not be used with xcode, it is an error. Copying is possible with the mouse.

In scenes other than xcode, such as browsers, you can operate both shortcut keys and mouse.

I do not know how to fix it. please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by deleting the shortcut key assignment by pressing the delete key while the conflicting run playground was selected.